# Split a string into fixed-size pieces using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a question - Im trying to split a variable stored into fixed-size by 5 characters and put a "%" after each 5. letter, with:

```
echo "$d" | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'
```

Which gives me this, if the stored variable in `$d` is `HELLOWOLRD123`

```
HELLO%WORLD%123
```

How can I get to auto fill out, `%%` so it keeps the fixed size as 5 ?

So my output is `HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%`

Comment: You want the letters in upper case after the conversion? i.e. `helloworld123` to `HELLO%WOLRD%123%%`

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%` ?

Comment: marcolz i do actually, didnt even notice that :)

Comment: In that case, `$(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))` would be the number of `%` you would want to pad in `bash` before passing it to `sed`.

Comment: Well i tried to past `$(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))` before my sed command, it outputs command not found :(

Comment: `$(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))`
`echo "$d" | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'` like this

Comment: My script is made to work only with upper case - so the stored in `$d` will already be uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
echo $(echo -n "$d"; printf "%`echo $(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))`s" | tr ' ' '%') | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'
```

EDIT:

For Mac(which doesn't support `echo -n`)

```
echo $(printf "$d"; printf "%`echo $(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))`s" | tr ' ' '%') | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'
```

Comment: I tried it, but i didnt give me the output i wanted its damn close though.

It outputs: `- n HE%LLOWO%RLD12% 3%%%`

Comment: edited above, I would like to see `HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%%`

Comment: That's very strange. What was your input? ``HELLOWOLRD123`` gave me the output ``HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%``. And try to execute this ``d=HELLOWOLRD123; echo $(echo -n "$d"; printf "%`echo $(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))`s" | tr ' ' '%') | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'`` and tell me the output.

Comment: `d=HELLOWOLRD123
echo $(echo -n "$d"; printf "%`echo $(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))`s" | tr ' ' '%') | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'
-n HE%LLOWO%LRD12%3 %%` 
I tried again without all of my other code, i get the same output

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php <- Enter the command there and you can see that it works. It's gotta be something on your end. Maybe old bash version?

Comment: #! bin/bash

`d=AREYOUHERE123;
echo $(echo -n "$d"; printf "%`echo $(((5 - (${#d} % 5)) % 5))`s" | tr ' ' '%') | sed 's/.\{5\}/&%/g'`I tried with a other input, this time my output was 

`-n AR%EYOUH%ERE12%3 %%` this should have been AREYO%UHERE%123%%%

Comment: It works as u say at tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php -> But not on my mac where i use Atom editor :/ do i need to change something in the syntax?

Comment: I found the mistake in apple terminal, it cant read the `-n` command, try it on tutorialspoint.com withoth the `-n` and u would get the same output.. seems like my macbook pro cant read the `-n` command

Comment: Then try ``printf "$d"`` instead of ``echo -n "$d"``. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If `perl` is okay

```
$ echo 'HELLOWOLRD123' | perl -pe 's/.{1,5}/$& . "%" x (6-length($&))/ge'
HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%
```

- `.{1,5}` greedy match 1 to 5 characters
- `e` this modifier allows us to use Perl code in replacement section
- `$&` the matched string
- `.` string concatenation
- `"%" x (6-length($&))` here `x` is string repetition operator

Answer (score 2):

One in awk:

```
$ echo HELLOWOLRD123 | 
  awk '{gsub(/.{1,5}/,"&%");while(length($0)%6)sub(/$/,"%")}1'
HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%
```

Explained some:

```
$ echo HELLOWOLRD123 | 
  awk '{
      gsub(/.{1,5}/,"&%")   # add % after every 5 chars
      while(length($0)%6)   # while length of string mod 6 is not 0
          sub(/$/,"%")      # add a & to it
  }1'
HELLO%WOLRD%123%%%
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
echo 'HELLOWOLRD123' | sed -E '
s/(.{5})/&%/g
s/%...$/&%%%/
t
s/%..$/&%%%%/
t
s/%.$/&%%%%%/'
```

Or with loop

```
echo 'HELLOWOLRD123' | sed -E '
s/(.{5})/&%/g
/%$/b
:A
/%.{6}$/!{
  s/$/#/
  bA
}
:B
  s/(.*%[^#]*)#(.*$)/\1%\2/
  tB'
```